# Why image compression is not as good as photoshop's?

Tags: image-optimization

I'm using jpegtran to optimize images. However when I save a picture from Photoshop the size of the picture is smaller then if I save an image and optimize it with jpegtran on my server.

Other thing I don't understand is that if I check my site by "http://www.webpagetest.org" it reports that I can still compress these images, in some cases it reports the size can be reduced by 30-40%!
What am I doing wrong?

My optimize command is the following:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize -progressive -outfile
```

Comment: If you're saving from Photoshop as a JPEG, chances are you're using lossy compression. You can tell jpegtran to do this with the `-quality` flag.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i did read about "http://www.webpagetest.org" that they use lossy compression comparison in their tests too, so that must be the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @ceejayoz i guess the answer is that both photoshop and both the mentioned website uses lossy compression, which can be set with the `-quality` flag in jpegtran.